# Display summary of choices in JS

Tags: javascript

this is my first time here as a poster, please be gentle! I have zero knowledge of JS (yet, working on it) but am required to do some JS anyway. Here's my problem. I got some code (not mine) allowing a user to select multiple choices. I found the function that gathers these choices and store them

```
function getProductAttribute()
{
    // get product attribute id
    product_attribute_id = $('#idCombination').val();
    product_id = $('#product_page_product_id').val();

    // get every attributes values
    request = '';
    //create a temporary 'tab_attributes' array containing the choices of the customer
    var tab_attributes = [];
    $('#attributes select, #attributes input[type=hidden], #attributes input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
        tab_attributes.push($(this).val());
    });


    // build new request
    for (var i in attributesCombinations)
        for (var a in tab_attributes)
            if (attributesCombinations[i]['id_attribute'] === tab_attributes[a])
                request += '/'+attributesCombinations[i]['group'] + '-' + attributesCombinations[i]['attribute'];
            $('#[attsummary]').html($('#[attsummary]').html() + attributesCombinations[i]['group']+': '+attributesCombinations[i]['attribute']+'<br/>')// DISPLAY ATTRIBUTES SUMMARY
    request = request.replace(request.substring(0, 1), '#/');
    url = window.location + '';

    // redirection
    if (url.indexOf('#') != -1)
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#'));

    // set ipa to the customization form
    $('#customizationForm').attr('action', $('#customizationForm').attr('action') + request);
    window.location = url + request;
}
```

I need to make a simple display summary of these choices. After quite a bit of searching and findling, I came with the line with the DISPLAY SUMMARY comment, this one:

`$('#[attsummary]').html($('#[attsummary]').html() + attributesCombinations[i]['group']+': '+attributesCombinations[i]['attribute']+'<br/>')`

In the page where I want those options, I added an empty div with the same ID (attsummary):

```
<div id="attsummary"></div>
```

Obviously, it is not working. I know I don't know JS, but naively I really thought this would do the trick. May you share with me some pointers as to where I went wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `$('#[attsummary]')` ---> `$('#attsummary')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct form of the line it isn't working for you:

```
$('#attsummary').html($('#attsummary').html() + attributesCombinations[i]['group']+': '+attributesCombinations[i]['attribute']+'<br/>')
```

Comment: Thanks, there was that, and there was me being an idiot. I missed braces around the line I added+the line above it; that fixed it. Thanks :)